# How to write a JEST test for a useEffect with timers?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am using `@react-native-community/netinfo` to detect the app connectivity state and showing a message when connection is lost. How do I write a test for the following code that's in a useEffect to make sure that the message is showing/hiding and the cleanup works?

```
  const { isConnected } = useContext(ConnectionContext); 
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const snack = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isConnected) {
        showMessage({
          autoHide: false,
          message: 'Please try again later',
        });
      }
    }, 10000);
    const hideSnack = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isConnected) hideMessage();
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(snack);
      clearTimeout(hideSnack);
    };
  }, [isConnected]);
```

I have tried something like this to check if the app is connected

```
jest.mock('@react-native-community/netinfo', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@react-native-community/netinfo'),
  useNetInfo: () => ({
    isConnected: true,
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jest fake timers to control the time:

at the top use

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

then when you need to advance time by certain amount use :

```
jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
```